# Get data from JSON by using a variable JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get data out of a JSON using a value.

I have an array of objects:

```
"fruits": [
    {
        "Name": "Orange",
        "Quantity": "5"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Apple",
        "Quantity": "2"
    }
 ]
```

And I also have the name "Apple". How can I get the quantity of Apples?

I'm stuck on this..

Thanks!

Comment: Are you starting with JSON or do you have a JavaScript object? In either case you are missing the outer braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fruits.find(fruit => fruit.Name==="Apple").Quantity` is what you are looking for:

```js
const fruits = [
    {
        "Name": "Orange",
        "Quantity": "5"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Apple",
        "Quantity": "2"
    }
 ]      
 
 console.log(fruits.find(fruit => fruit.Name==="Apple").Quantity);
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using a forEach you can check each element and if the Name matches get the Quantity

```js
var fruits = [{
    "Name": "Orange",
    "Quantity": "5"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Apple",
    "Quantity": "2"
  }
]

fruits.forEach(function(element) {
  if (element.Name === 'Apple') {
    console.log(element.Quantity)
  }
});
```